# How to store large books in elasticsearch to perform full-text search over the entire content

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, large-data

I would like to perform full-text search on data set that holds relatively large items (text books with up to tens of megabytes each). Can `elasticsearch` somehow handle it? I see that it has a default limit for `text` field which is about 32KB (version 8.0).
By googling around I found out that many blog posts propose to store pages as a separate documents instead of entire books. Other blogs talk about `nested` type. I event found some very exotic stuff when books are split into multiple fields in a single document but it will not work for me because a document has it's own limit of 100KB.

What would be the best way to do this? Or I should consider something else besides *elasticsearch*?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2GB limit on documents size. check this discussion thread elastic search team member.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/maximum-document-size/13086

Try splitting the book into pages where each page is a document.